# ¿Crear tablas y campos en ingles o español Laravel?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Estoy empezando a crear un proyecto con laravel y quisiera saber que es mejor o que me recomiendan mas , crear mis tablas y campos en ingles o en español , cabe resaltar que mi pregunta solo se refiere a la base de datos porque que la intefaz y todo lo de mas sera en español(menu , formulario etc.).

Comment: bienvenido, favor de leer [ask]; pues las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Comment: Por favor no pedir opiniones, ya debes saber (después de tantas preguntas que has formulado) que no son bienvenidas en el sitio.

Comment: no se como me pides que no pida opiniones , si este es un sitio precisamente para eso.

Comment: entonces les hago esta pregunta a ustdes para no volver a tenes este tipo de problemas , si tengo una pregunta  o mejor dicho si pido una opinion como la que acabo de hacer , no la puedo hacer en este sitio?

Comment: Puedes ocupar el [chat]

Comment: ok muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En si, no hay problema en que estén en español, aunque si quieres ahorrarte algo de tiempo configurando, te recomiendo que hagas un "espanglish".

Ya que los nombres de los modelos, por ejemplo "opinion". Laravel asume que su tabla es ese nombre mas "s". Es decir, "opinions" en lugar de "opiniones".

Con respecto a las relaciones entre tablas, las referencias a una id de otra tabla por defecto laravel utiliza el nombre del modelo + "_id". Por ejemplo, si quiero referenciar la id de una opinion. La columna en mi tabla sera "opinion_id".

Claramente, siempre es recomendable evitar "ñ", tildes, etc.

Comment: se te agradece la intención, pero preguntas basadas en opiniones no se deben responder

Comment: si creo las tablas en ingles y los campos de las tabla en español estaria mal ?

Comment: Siento haber respondido a una pregunta de opinión, a mi parecer era más bien una pregunta de si había algún problema en usar tablas en español. Y para cerrar el tema, simplemente añado, para responder al comentario del creador de la pregunta: puedes usar los nombres da igual el idioma y mezclar cuanto quieras, solo ten en cuenta lo que te marque en la respuesta sobre la configuración inicial de Laravel.

Comment: Por favor no vuelvas a responder este tipo de preguntas @FranciscoGarrido, gracias.